# fill_parent not filling parent?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working with the new 10.1 galaxy tab google handed out at IO.  I'm new to android layout but the Graphical Layout in eclipse looks fine but my app does not fill the parent on the tab.

This is my `main.xml`:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:background="@color/red"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
 </LinearLayout>
```

This is what i see[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add next tag to your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<manifest>
...
    <supports-screens     
        android:resizeable="true" />
</manifest>
```

You can find more information about this tag [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html).

Comment: In the link you gave it says this should be true by default and makes it sound like it's been deprecated since 1.6 - in fact it says "You should not use it".  Why wasn't it default for the user above (using at least Android 3)?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this explanation of Screen Compatibility mode would help solve the problem: 
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screen-compat-mode.html